# How set annotation in k8s for GitLab by HELM

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

GitLab required annotations `app.gitlab.com/app=$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG` and `app.gitlab.com/env=$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` for k8s deployments/pods

How can I set these values to use Helm?

I try scripts:

```
script:
- env
- help upgrade $RELEASE_NAME $HELM_PATH 
  --set deploy.annotations.app\.gitlab\.com\/env=$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG 
  --set deploy.annotations.app\.gitlab\.com\/app=$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG
  --install
  --wait
  --namespace=$KUBE_NAMESPACE
  --create-namespace=true;
```

But this set only `app.gitlab.com/app`
But no set value in `app.gitlab.com/env`

How can I fix it?

P.S. I think that the `--set` overrides and stores the last value.

env:

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG=google-staging-sh-xxxxxx
CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG=groupName-projectName
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass your config data during `helm install`? Or are you using any other method?

Comment: Do you include the annotations in your YAML files, or in the `_helpers.tpl` file somewhere?  For debugging, can you dump out `{{ toYaml .Values.deploy.annotations }}` somewhere and run `helm template` to see what gets rendered?

Comment: @DavidMaze I use `{{- toYaml .Values.deploy.annotations | nindent 4 }}`

helm template return 

`annotations:
        app.gitlab.com/app: shortlink-org-shortlink \n
        app.gitlab.com/env: ""`